# Graph - raining animation with lightning in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make graph with raining animation and this example or lightning scatter is closest I have found.

But both work with random numbers. Is there a way how to implement actual rain data to graph for years?

How can I put in data for years and rainfall? And they will be shown based on rainfall quantity (size and frequency)

Thank you.

```
from lightning import Lightning
from numpy import random

lgn = Lightning()

x = random.randn(100)
y = random.randn(100)
group = (random.rand(100) * 5).astype('int')
size = random.rand(100) * 20 + 5

lgn.scatter(x, y, group=group, size=size)
```